# React Lazy Loading Issue in 16.13.0

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-lazy-load

```
import React, { Component,lazy,Suspense} from 'react';
import LayoutComponent from './components/layout/Layout'
import BurgerBuilderContainer from './Containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder'
import CheckoutContainer from './Containers/CheckOut/Checkout'
import { Route, Switch,withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
 const OrdersContainer = lazy(()=> {
  return import('./Containers/Orders/Orders')
 })
```

[image: Error Facing]

```
render(){
return (
  <div>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    <LayoutComponent>
      <Switch>
      <Route path="/Logout" component={LogoutContainer}></Route>
      <Route path="/Auth" component={AuthContainer}></Route>
        <Route path="/Orders" component={OrdersContainer}></Route>
        <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutContainer}></Route>
        <Route path="/" component={BurgerBuilderContainer}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </LayoutComponent>
    </Suspense>
  </div>
);
}
```

AsPer the error lazy loading is showing error on import, before using lazy loading application was working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try with

```
const OrdersContainer= React.lazy(() => import('./Containers/Orders/Orders'));
```

if error continues try

```
const OrdersContainer= React.lazy(() => require('./Containers/Orders/Orders'));
```

if still continues

```
React.lazy(() => import("./Containers/Orders/Orders").then(x => x.default))
```

lastly

import `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`

Comment: thanks for the response. but i have tried this too but its not working same error

Comment: are you using create-react-app? if it is so which version of it?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "prop-type": "0.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
     "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
      }     Please Have a look

Comment: can  you please try `require` instead of `import`? also make sure that lazy loading declaration is after all module imports

Comment: yes, require is working....thanks for the resolving but can you tell me why i am not able to use 'import' i am using higher version which support same in other projects...

Comment: I believe that it is about the javascript version rather then react itself